# Design pattern for iOS Puzzle Game

Tags: objective-c, ios, puzzle

I am trying to create an iOS based Puzzle game using Objective C. There would be at least 30 different kinds of puzzles/games including mazes, tic tac toe, small crosswords etc., all in one iOS game. How do I proceed with the creation of Views, View Controllers etc., Do I host every puzzle in a separate UIView and load it as subview when necessary, or use separate UIViewControllers for every puzzle and navigate among them? I'll be reusing the puzzle again and again with slight changes during the course of the application - i.e., A Tic Tac Toe would be displayed first, followed by a maze, then the same tic tac toe would be displayed, but with different background, colors, etc., Which is the commonly used and best design pattern for this kind of application for creating view, view controllers and holding the images, colors, progress in memory?

Comment: What have you learned so far in your research that would enable you to at least get started designing such a game?  Have you looked at other similar games from open source communities?  Maybe your first step is to get *something* tangible built.  Start with the Tic-Tac-Toe game (complete with the custom colors, etc.) then see how you can refactor that code to support a new type of puzzle.

Comment: Well, the problem I have is with the integration of these puzzles. I can build the puzzles individually, but if you want to integrate, say 10 puzzles in 1, what is the best way to integrate them?

Answer (score 0):

You first need to make a menu(class) so the player can decide which game they want to play.

1. Create a new class (example mainMenuScene)
2. make sure the new class displays your menu png and any or all buttons.
3. Don't forget to import your class (mainMenuScene) on your view controller.
4. Make sure your viewController starts with MainMenuScene first.
5. Then implement touchesBegan in your MainMenuScene so when the user taps it. the app will trans to the game tapped.
6. setup all games in different classes and have all classes wired up to the story board.

That is how I would do it but of course there are a billion ways.

another way would be to use a table view controller listing your games. Then wire up all games in the storyboard.

Comment: after re-reading your question, I realized you maybe trying to hook your games up in-line. if this is the case, just make a endGame method within the current game that sends the player to the next game.